# Optimization of code removing extra if and else block

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, java, code

I need to remove the extra if and else loop as per the req and need to make it short for reading of the code should be easy.
can anyone suggest some better for below:

```
if (data[0].FA_N__c) {
            if (test === false) {
                this.cl = acL;
            }
            else if (test === true) {
                this.cl = acWo;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (test === false) {
                this.cl = nAc;
            }
            else if (test === true) {
                this.cl = nAcWo;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If we're talking about readability, I don't find those variable names very readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make use of [Conditional (ternary) operator in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to make your code short:-

```
        if (data[0].FA_N__c) {
            this.cl = test ? acWo : acL;
        }else {
            this.cl = test ? nAcWo : nAc;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more context of where the code is structured in will be fine :)

When you have the possibility to make a return, you can do something like this:

```
if (data[0].FA_N__c) {
  if (test === false) {
    this.cl = acL;
    return;
  }

  this.cl = acWo;
  return;
}

if (test === false) {
  this.cl = nAc;
  return;
}

this.cl = nAcWo;
```

When your are inside a loop, you can replace the return with a continue.